# Convert List of Objects to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a list of Object DTO's for which I want to convert to JSON using `json_encode`

Object: CouponDTO.php

```
class CouponDTO
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
}
```

I have an array of objects, now I need to convert that array of objects to JSON, I tried json_encode, but it provided below empty result.

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

Below is the code to create array of objects:

```
$couponDTOs = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $couponDTO = new CouponDTO();
    $couponDTO->setId("1");
    $couponDTO->setTitle("title");
    array_push($couponDTOs, $couponDTO);
}
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": title
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": title
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": title
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": title
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": title
    },
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613792/how-do-i-json-encode-private-properties-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710347/json-encode-an-array-of-objects-with-private-properties

Comment: I searched a lot, but I was not at all aware that it was because of private member variables.